# show this function $f(m,n)=f(n,m)$.

Tags: functions

> let $m,n\in \mathbb N^{+}$,and such that $$f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)-nf(m-1,n-1)$$
>   and $f(m,0)=f(0,n)=1$.
>
> show that $f(m,n)=f(n,m)$.

I have found
$$f(m,1)=-mn+1$$
$$f(m,1)=f(m-1,1)-n$$
so we have
$$f(m,1)=-mn+f(0,1)=-mn+1$$

Comment: interestingly, the symmetry does not arise from the equation itself, but is given by the initial conditions.

Comment: Have you thought about induction on m and n separately, or on the difference of m and n, or something else?

Answer (score 12):

> First, let us find a simple bound: We have $|f(n,m)| \le m! n!$

In fact, for $m=0$ or $n=0$ this is true. If then $m=1$, we have
$$f(1,n) = f(0,n) - n f(0,n-1) = 1- n.$$ Thus, we can suppose that $m \ge 2$. Then by induction, we get that
\begin{align}
|f(m,n)| &\le |f(m-1,n)| + n |f(m-1,n-1)| \\
& \le (m-1)! n! + n (m-1)! (n-1)! = 2[n! (m-1)!] \le n! m!.
\end{align}

> Next we determine the exponential generating function. (We will see that this function is symmetric.)

Note that we don't know if the generating function is convergent in an appropriate region. Therefore, we need to consider the exponential generating function.

Define
$$G(z,w) = \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{f(m,n)}{m!n!} z^m w^n$$
and note that $G(z,w)$ is analytic on $|z|,|w|  < 1$. Using the recurrence relation, we find
\begin{align*}
G(z,w) &=  (e^z +e^w-1) + \sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \frac{f(m,n)}{m!n!} z^m w^n \\
&=  (e^z +e^w-1) + \sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \Big(\frac{f(m-1,n)}{m!n!} - \frac{f(m-1,n-1)}{m! (n-1)!} \Big) z^m w^n \\
&= e^w + \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{f(m,n)}{(m+1)!n!} z^{m+1} w^n - \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{f(m,n)}{(m+1)! n!}  z^{m+1} w^{n+1} \\
&= e^w+ \int_0^z G(t,w) \, dt - \int_0^z w G(t,w) \, dt 
\end{align*}
This leads to the ordinary differential equation
$$G_z(z,w) = (1-w) G(z,w).$$
Thus $G(z,w) = C(w) \exp ((1-w) z)$. Since $e^w = G(0,w) = C(w)$ we find that $$G(z,w) = \exp(z+w-zw).$$
The last identity implies that $G(z,w) =G(w,z)$ and thus the taylor coefficients must be symmetric, too.

> Moreover, we can use this result in order determine an explicit formula for $f(n,m)$.

In fact, we have
\begin{align*}
\exp(z+w-zw) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (z+w-zw)^n \\
& = \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty z^m w^n \sum_{n= k_1+k_3, m= k_2+k_3} (-1)^{k_3} \frac{1}{k_1! k_2! k_3!}
\end{align*}

and therefore
$$f(n,m) = n! m! \sum_{n= k_1+k_3, m= k_2+k_3} (-1)^{k_3} \frac{1}{k_1! k_2! k_3!}.$$

Comment: Well done (+1). Just edit $w^m \to w^n$ in the first sum. Note that you can use the e.g.f. as a formal series, without caring of convergence

Comment: Yes, the exponential generating function can be seen as a formal power series. Then "integrating" is only a formal map defined on the ring of all formal power series. However, if we solve the ODE as usual, then we need that this solution is also analytic. (If we consider only the generating function, we get a singular ODE in $z,w=0$. In fact, it can be solved in terms of the exponential integral. However, the solution is not analytic and, therefore, we cannot conclude that $f(m,n)=f(n,m)$.)

Comment: @p4sch: You can always uniquely solve an ODE of the form $\partial_z f = gf$ for $f$ in FPS (where $g$ is a fixed FPS) under the assumption that $f$ has constant term $1$. So there is no need for analyticity. Maybe some degree of analyticity is necessary to make your two integrals well-defined, but you could avoid those by taking the $z$-derivative first.

Comment: For the generating function (not exponential generating function) one gets an ODE of the form $\partial_z f = gf + h$ and $h$ has a singularity in $z=0$, resp. $w=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, first it's clear that, for $m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ $$f(m,0)=f(m-1,0)=f(m-2,0)=\ldots=f(m-(m-1),0)=f(1,0)=1$$ Therefore, 
$$f(m,1)=f(1,1)-f(1,0)-f(2,0)-f(3,0)-\ldots-f(m-1,0)=f(1,1)-(m-1)$$
$$=1-f(0,0)-(m-1)=2-f(0,0)-m\qquad (*)$$

For the other hand, $$f(1,m)=f(0,m)-mf(0,m-1)=1-m$$ From where it follows that, $f(1,1)=0$. Therefore, by $(*)$ we have $0=f(1,1)=1-f(0,0)$, i.e., $f(0,0)=1$. And from $(*)$ we have, $f(m,1)=1-m$. So, in this case, we have $f(1,m)=f(m,1)$.

Another realtion, that maybe help us is that $$f(2,m+1)=f(1,m+1)-(m+1)f(1,m)=m^2-m-1$$

From this, $f(2,2)=-1$ and for other hand $f(2,2)=f(1,2)-2f(1,1)=(1-2)-2*0=-1$. So this makes me think that the function is symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

With the MATHEMATICA script

```
Clear[f]
f[m_, n_] := If[(n > 0) && (m > 0), f[m - 1, n] - n f[m - 1, n - 1], 1]
Table[f[m, n], {m, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}] // MatrixForm
```

we have the table for the first $10\times 10$ values

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 & -5 & -6 & -7 & -8 & -9 \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 5 & 11 & 19 & 29 & 41 & 55 & 71 \\
 1 & -2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & -14 & -47 & -104 & -191 & -314 & -479 \\
 1 & -3 & 5 & 1 & -15 & -19 & 37 & 225 & 641 & 1405 & 2661 \\
 1 & -4 & 11 & -14 & -19 & 56 & 151 & -34 & -1159 & -4364 & -11389 \\
 1 & -5 & 19 & -47 & 37 & 151 & -185 & -1091 & -887 & 6067 & 32251 \\
 1 & -6 & 29 & -104 & 225 & -34 & -1091 & 204 & 7841 & 14050 & -28419 \\
 1 & -7 & 41 & -191 & 641 & -1159 & -887 & 7841 & 6209 & -56519 & -168919 \\
 1 & -8 & 55 & -314 & 1405 & -4364 & 6067 & 14050 & -56519 & -112400 & 396271 \\
 1 & -9 & 71 & -479 & 2661 & -11389 & 32251 & -28419 & -168919 & 396271 & 1520271 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

as can we verify $f(m,n) = f(n,m)$

Comment: Is this an un-formal verification ?

Comment: @GCab Yes. I did it for checking purposes.